# Interpreting Stumps in Boosted Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, boosting

I have trained a binary classifier using the `LogitBoost()`function from the `caTools` package. When I inspect the decision stumps with `$Stump`, one of my predictor variables has been included twice in the model, albeit with the same values for threshold and sign. How should I interpret this? Is this variable of particular importance to the model I have trained?